# How can I get all instances of one type form Java List?

Tags: java, generics

I have some parts in my code that look like this:

```java
A, B and C extend D

public ArrayList<A> getA() {
    ArrayList<A> allElements = new ArrayList<A>();
    for (D el : listOfDs) {
        if (el instanceof A) {
            allElements.add((A) el);
        }
    }
    return allElements;
}

public ArrayList<B> getB() {
    ArrayList<B> allElements = new ArrayList<B>();
    for (D el : listOfDs) {
        if (el instanceof B) {
            allElements.add((B) el);
        }
    }
    return allElements;
}

public ArrayList<C> getC() {
    ArrayList<C> allElements = new ArrayList<C>();
    for (D el : listOfDs) {
        if (el instanceof C) {
            allElements.add((C) el);
        }
    }
    return allElements;
}
```

I would like to combine all of them to one method like this:

```java
public <T> ArrayList<T> get() {
    ArrayList<T> allElements = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (D el : listOfDs) {
        if (el instanceof T) {
            allElements.add((T) el);
        }
    }
    return allElements;
}
```

Is this possible in Java?

At the moment I get

> Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use instead
>   its erasure Object instead since further generic type information will
>   be erased at runtime

and

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Node to T

Then I've tried this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> ArrayList<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
    ArrayList<T> allElements = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(D o : listOfDs) {
        if (o.getClass() == clazz) {
            allElements.add((T) o);
        }
    }
    return allElements;
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors, but how can I call it? This did not work:

```
get(A);
```

Comment: What is the type of list of Ds ? Cant you get a list of Ds as List<? extends D> ?

Comment: p.s. you should use `clazz.isInstance(o)` instead of `o.getClass() == clazz`. `clazz.isInstance(o)` will work when `o` is of a subclass of `clazz`, just like `instanceof`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Iterables.filter`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29) from Guava.

Example usage:

```
Iterable<X> xs = Iterables.filter(someIterable, X.class);
```

Since it's an open source library, you can check out the source to find what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks, X.class was what I was looking for :-) But it is nice to know that Iterables.filer exists.